# How to prove that this relation is antisymmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let $F$ be the set of all functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. A relation $c$ is defined on $F$ by
$f c g$ if and only if $f(x) ≤ g(x)$ for all $x ∈ \mathbb{R} $.
Prove that '$c$' is a partial order.

I have proved that the relation is *reflexive*. Now I must prove that it is *antisymmetric* (and later *transitive*).

My working thus far:

Suppose $a, b ∈ F$. We must prove that if $a c b$ and $b c a$ then $a = b$. Now, if $a c b$ and $b c a$ then $f(a) ≤ f(b)$ and $f(b) ≤ f(a)$. Therefore, $f(a) = f(b)$.

*Now, how to prove that $a = b$? There is no indication that $f$ is an injective function.*

Comment: The relation is on the set of functions, not the reals. $f$ is a variable!

Comment: Oops, my mistake everyone...apologies, and sincere thanks to all who helped :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confuse about your own notation.  You define the relation as

> Let $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ be the set of all functions $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. So define $\color{blue}{c}$ as the relation defined on $\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ as, for $f,g \in \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ then $f \color{blue} c g \Leftrightarrow f(x)\leq g(x) \, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now take a look in your proof: You say that $a,b \in \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ and then in your proof you use $a,b$ as variables for $f,g$! But your answer is not all wrong. Let's see it

Suppose $a,b \in \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$. [We want to prove that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation) $(a \color{blue }c b $ and $b \color{blue}c a )$ implies $a = b$. Now what you've done is

1. $a \color{blue}c b \implies \color{red}\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, a(x)\color{red}\leq b(x)$
2. $b \color{blue}ca \implies \color{red}\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, b(x)\color{red}\leq a(x)$

And then $\color{red}{(1)\text{ and } (2)\text{ together}}$ implies that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, a(x) = b(x)$ wich implies that $a = b \in \mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$. In blue is the relation and in red is important things that should be in your argument. Now you should try to answer transitive. But that should follow directly from arguments of inequality as the one above.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much Rafael. Yes, I just realised I confused the notation! :)

Comment: 0/ ok thats fine  0/

Answer (score 1):

The relation is over the set of functions, $F$, and not on the set of real numbers, $\mathbb R$.

So, here, your $a$s and $b$s are elements of $F$, i.e., functions that map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

In your case, $a c b$ means $a \le b$, where $a$ and $b$ are functions in $F$. It does not mean $f(a) \le f(b)$.

Hence, showing $f=g$ is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that this is a relation on the functions, not the elements. You seem to be getting confused with this difference. If $f \prec g$ and $g \prec f$ then $f(x) \leq g(x)$ and $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for all $x \in R$. This means $f=g$. No need for injectivity :)